# How to count records of multiple tables that match the results of a base table in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below returns all the names of the procedures table and the count of matched results in table1, as follows:

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(t1.id) as Quantity
FROM procedures p
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON p.id = t1.id
GROUP BY p.name ASC
```

How can i make the query above but making count of many other tables? Imagine that i have 2 more tables to count and the query output the columns like this:

```
Name Quantity1 Quantity2 Quantity3
A        0       100        27
B        10      0          15
C        50      200        1
```

Procedures table:

```
id   name
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

The other tables that i want to count the matching results based on Procedures

table1, table2, table3...

```
id   name
1     A
1     A
1     A
2     B
2     B
3     C
3     C
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Duplicates make this tricky.

Comment: I put some sample data to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Join the other tables as well:

```
SELECT p.name, 
       COUNT(t1.id) as Quantity1, 
       COUNT(t2.id) as Quantity2,
       COUNT(t3.id) as Quantity3
FROM   procedures p
       LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON p.id = t1.id
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON p.id = t2.id
       LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON p.id = t3.id
GROUP  BY p.name ASC
```

Comment: I tried your solution, a display is done as I wanted, but the count values are strange, it looks like one column is affecting the count of the others, for example: Quantity1 has procedure A equal to 20, this value is correct, but in Quantity 2 The same procedure A that should be equal to 5, appears as 20, repeating the same value of Quantity2. Do you have any idea how to do all these counts in isolation, without any interference between columns?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to aggregate before the `join`:

```
SELECT p.name, SUM(t1.cnt1) as cnt1
FROM procedures p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*) as cnt1
      FROM table1 t1
      GROUP BY t1.id
     ) t1
     ON p.id = t1.id
GROUP BY p.name ASC;
```

Hmmm, you are still going to get duplicates when if `name` and `id` are not 1-1.  If that is an issue, then:

```
SELECT p.name, t1.cnt1 as cnt1
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name
      FROM procedures p
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT p.name, COUNT(*) as cnt1
      FROM table1 t1 JOIN
           procedures p
           ON p.id = t1.id
      GROUP BY p.name
     ) t1
     ON p.name = t1.name;
```

This approach will generalize safely.